# How to get SignedData and Signature for android LVL

Tags: php, android, server-side

I try to implement a server side verification of an android license.
I use the php code : http://code.google.com/p/android-market-license-verification/

In the file sample/verify.php, I have two lines to complete :

```
$responseData = '';
$signature = '';
```

I see in the google LVL that there is a function called verify which has these parameters.

```
public void verify(PublicKey publicKey, int responseCode, String signedData, String signature);
```

But I don't know how to get datas to send them on my webserver

Where can I get the ResponseData and signature ?

Thank you,